# Server does not execute Page Load event when re-entering URL in browser

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page (page.aspx) and in the page load event I have a code to generate a `.txt` file. Here is the sequence of actions:

1. type the address in the address bar of IE browser (e.g. `http://localhost/somesite/page.aspx`) --> this will execute the page load event and generate the `txt` file.
2. Delete the generated file above and In the same browser(page), re-type the same url (http://localhost/somesite/page.aspx) --> this will not execute the page load event and will not generate the `txt` file
3. Click the refresh button on the browser, now it executes the page load event and generates the `txt` file.

Why does the server not execute the `Page_Load` event when the same page is reloaded without using the browser refresh button? Is this some sort of page level cache?

Answer (score 1):

Try using a tool such as [Fiddler](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CBsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fiddler2.com%2F&rct=j&q=fiddler&ei=4qjCTNGjI42T4ga96fS5Aw&usg=AFQjCNGyVxcKeoiBFf3LsfsM8apoKVxKLQ&sig2=5Ob9vlCG8wdUmAHog2zlUg&cad=rja) to monitor the `HTTP` requests and responses. Pay special attention to the [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header. Step 2 probably doesn't even talk to the server since the page has not expired yet.

Comment: fiddler cannot detect localhost I believe!

Comment: Of course [it can](http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/hookup.asp#Q-LocalTraffic) :)